# IOS Label Inside Table Cell Only Showing One Letter

Tags: ios, uitableview

Preface: I am very new to swift and my have missed something stupid

Here is the picture of one table cell, as seen in the app's storyboard:[image]

The issue is that when I run my code, in which I tried to simply create five of these same cells, I get this:

[image]

When I try to populate the cells programmatically, it cuts off the words after one letter!

I created a table and the screen's view controller implements the proper interfaces:
 `UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

here is my `cellsForRowAt` function which I implemented because I am implementing the `TableViewDelegate` Interface (actually, it was because the tutorial I was following did it)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentity", for: indexPath) as? YeezyCell{
        let dataObject = videoDatas[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateUI(data: dataObject)

        return cell
    }
```

`videoDatas` is a class I made which should have no problems. Its use here is that it returns the text for the label.

`cellIdentity` is what I set the identity of the table cell as, in the identity inspector.

All `updateUI()` does is this:

```
func updateUI(data: MusicVideoData){
    videoTitle.text = data.getTitle()
    print(videoTitle.text)
}
```

and `videoTitle` is simply an `IBOutlet` I made connecting the label I am referring to, to the code.

My print statement is printing `famous` so it looks like for some reason the label is cutting off that text after the first letter?

I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain why.

Thanks a lot for any help.

If more of my files are necessary to answer my question, please let me know and I will post them.

Comment: Are you using constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using proper constraints for the image already.

Set the constraints of your `label` like so in interface builder:

- pin leading (left) to image
- pin trailing (right) to superview
- set vertical constraint to superview